# Automated OSGi dependency resolution for bundles that are maven-accessible?

Tags: java, dependencies, osgi

It seem that there is already a fairly automated method to link, at least on the server, dependencies with their available bundles in a Maven repository, e.g., 
http://www.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/dependencies?name=org.springframework.osgi.extensions.annotations&version=1.2.1

It seems like this would be a great tool (a la Maven but for bundles - and I don't mean simply specifying them in a pom file like used by the provision task of the maven-pax-plugin.

Does such a tool exist yet? Ideally a free one?

Thank you
Yours
Misha

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OSGi Bundle Repository or O.B.R.](http://www.osgi.org/Repository/HomePage)